# Apple Mach-O Linker Error after copying project to a new Laptop

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just got a new laptop and copied my project from one to the other. After trying to run the project on a device I get the following error.

```
Ld /Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Audeo.app/Audeo normal arm64
cd "/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo ios"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -L/Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/bobbygetka/Desktop/Audeo/Audeo\ ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Intermediates/Audeo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Audeo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Audeo.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -lASBPlayerScrubbing -lGGLCore -lGGLSignIn -lGIDExShared -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMOAuth2_external -lGTMOAuth2_internal -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lOpenInChrome -lSignIn -framework AVFoundation -framework AddressBook -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Intermediates/Audeo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Audeo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Audeo.swiftmodule -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Intermediates/Audeo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Audeo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Audeo_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bobbygetka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Audeo-bxvmiakxxisgbxhewpfkhucpbwiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Audeo.app/Audeo

ld: library not found for -lASBPlayerScrubbing
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked at other similar questions, but none seem to help, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

please clean up your search path in your project.it will work fine...

and in your project file see whether you have "CoreData.framework".i have solved my problem like this only..

Comment: How would I go about cleaning up the search path? Also where would CoreData.framework be?